# Changing xib name

Tags: ios, xib

I have changed the xib name but the change done is not reflected in the xml file of the xib. I just changed the name by renaming the file in project navigator. am i missing something?

**Edit:**
The project is under version control. and I have tried refactoring.

**Edit 2:**
The issue was i was not changing the owner name referenced from xib and that was the problem in the xml of xib

Comment: @AKV No :( The xib name is changing in the project navigator, But inside the xml file "No"

Comment: You are checking the xml of xib???  Why dont you create a new xib with new name and copy all elements onto it?

Comment: @AKV  
I can do that. But changing name in project navigator and the xml file is easier than that right?. And the change in the project was supposed to be reflected in the xml also right? why is this not happening? any idea?

Comment: What kind of change do you expect? You change a file name, good, but what else should change accordingly?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe The class name in the xml file of the xib must change accordingly

Comment: So you wanted to change a class name? Why did you change the name of the xib, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try opening the corresponding .m or .h file, selecting the class name, right clicking and choosing Refactor -> Rename... ?

That should update the .m, .h and .xib files, as well as the project file.

Comment: I tried refactoring, but somehow it manages to miss the xml file

Comment: I suppose you could try opening the .xib file in a text editor, and do a find and replace?

Comment: I have to do that. But the question is why should i do that? It was supposed to happen all by itself right? I dont want a work around.

Comment: Did you try refactoring on a clean version of everything, having not changed anything? If so, I have no idea why it doesn't work. If not, you could go back to a version without any names changed (if you're using some revision control) and try refactoring again.

Comment: well thanks, But for some reason that did not help

Comment: Then I am at a loss. I suppose all that's left to do is find & replace or creating a new .xib file, as someone suggested above.